# How to get values of keys of inside array in json array

Tags: java, json, gson

This is the string that I get which I want to parse as json and get the values of "s", "o", "c" and "p" .

```
{
    "head": {
        "vars": [
            "s",
            "c",
            "o",
            "p"
        ]
    },
    "results": {
        "bindings": [
            {
                "s": {
                    "type": "uri",
                    "value": "http://example.org/data/window"
                },
                "c": {
                    "type": "uri",
                    "value": "http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/FeatureOfInterest"
                },
                "o": {
                    "type": "uri",
                    "value": "http://example.org/data/window104state"
                },
                "p": {
                    "type": "uri",
                    "value": "http://www.w3.org/ns/ssn/hasProperty"
                }
            },
                        {
                "s": {
                    "type": "uri",
                    "value": "http://example.org/data/earth"
                },
                "c": {
                    "type": "uri",
                    "value": "http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/FeatureOfInterest"
                },
                "o": {
                    "type": "uri",
                    "value": "http://example.org/data/VCAB-DP1-BP-40location"
                },
                "p": {
                    "type": "uri",
                    "value": "http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/hasSample"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This is the code I have tried so far:

```
JsonParser jsonParser =  new JsonParser();
JsonElement element = jsonParser.parse(str);
JsonObject obj = element.getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject results = obj.get("results").getAsJsonObject();
for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : results.entrySet()) {
            JsonArray array = entry.getValue().getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("bindings");
            for (JsonElement jsonElement : array) {
                 for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry1 : jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
                     System.out.println("Key = " + entry1.getKey() + " Value = " + entry1.getValue() );
                }
            }
```

What I want to get is the values of the inside array as such:
"s": "http://example.org/data/earth"
"c": "http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/FeatureOfInterest"
etc.
Instead I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: [{"s":{"type":"uri","value":"http://example.org/data/window"},"c":{"type":"uri","value":"http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/FeatureOfInterest"},"o":{"type":"uri","value":"http://example.org/data/window104state"},
```

(the whole string).

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @Deadpool I managed to get the values but now I need to get the "inner" values of the bindings meaning the "value" part of each binding(s,c,p and o). I need only this part and not the "type" part.
This is the result thanks to @Deadpool:

```
Key = s Value = {"type":"uri","value":"http://example.org/data/window"}
Key = c Value = {"type":"uri","value":"http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/FeatureOfInterest"}
Key = p Value = {"type":"uri","value":"http://www.w3.org/ns/ssn/hasProperty"}
Key = o Value = {"type":"uri","value":"http://example.org/data/window104state"}
```

**SOLUTION**
OK for those interested I managed to get it this the statement that was needed:

```
System.out.println("Key = " + entry1.getKey() + " Value = " + entry1.getValue().getAsJsonObject().get("value"));
```

And this is the desired result:

```
Key = s Value = "http://example.org/data/earth"
Key = c Value = "http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/FeatureOfInterest"
Key = o Value = "http://example.org/data/VCAB-DP1-BP-40location"
Key = p Value = "http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/hasSample"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this statement `bindings` is a `JsonArray`, get it as `JsonArray` directly

```
JsonArray array = entry.getValue().getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("bindings");
```

**Solution**

```
for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : results.entrySet()) {
        JsonArray array = entry.getValue().getAsJsonArray();
        for (JsonElement jsonElement : array) {
             for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry1 : jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
                 System.out.println("Key = " + entry1.getKey() + " Value = " + entry1.getValue() );
            }
        }
```

Comment: the statement is syntactically wrong:The method getAsJsonArray() in the type JsonElement is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Comment: check my updated code @SteliosBotonakis, just remove that string parameter `"bindings"`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Declarative Stream Mapping (DSM)](https://mfatihercik.github.io/dsm) stream parsing library to easily capture data from XML or JSON

First of all, you must define the mapping between JSON data and your fields in yaml or JSON format.

Here are the mapping definitions:

```
result:     
   type: array
   path: /results/bindings/(s|c|o|p)   // regex
   fields:
     key:
       path: type
     value:
```

Java class that you want to deserialize:

```
public class KeyValue{
    public String key;
    public String value
}
```

Java Code to parse JSON:

```
DSM dsm=new DSMBuilder(new File("path/to/mapping.yaml")).create(KeyValue.class);
List<KeyValue> list=  (List<KeyValue>)dsm.toObject(jsonData);
// write root object as json
dsm.getObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(System.out, list);
```

Here is output:

```
    [ {
  "key" : "uri",
  "value" : "http://example.org/data/window"
}, {
  "key" : "uri",
  "value" : "http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/FeatureOfInterest"
}, {
  "key" : "uri",
  "value" : "http://example.org/data/window104state"
}, {
  "key" : "uri",
  "value" : "http://www.w3.org/ns/ssn/hasProperty"
}, {
  "key" : "uri",
  "value" : "http://example.org/data/earth"
}, {
  "key" : "uri",
  "value" : "http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/FeatureOfInterest"
}, {
  "key" : "uri",
  "value" : "http://example.org/data/VCAB-DP1-BP-40location"
}, {
  "key" : "uri",
  "value" : "http://www.w3.org/ns/sosa/hasSample"
} ]
```